# Report Manager doesn't show all options

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, configuration, reporting-services

I've got an instance of SQL Server 2008 Enterprise with Reporting Services installed also.

I am hosting and administering this locally.

My issue is that when I connect to the Report Manager web application I only get the
Home|My Subscriptions|Help menu in the upper right hand corner.

I am connecting using Windows Integrated Authentication and the user account is assigned the admin role in Windows.

Apparently my account is in the regular user role.

How can I get it into an admin role?

Is there a default administrator role?  What is the default password?

Should I just start from scratch and reinstall SQL Server?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chuck

Comment: have you tried connecting via browser but from the server console?

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to be set up as a local admin on the ssrs server to do this.

go to site settings- Configure site-wide security- and add yourself
then on the home page, add yourself to the home folder.